# "column new.total does not exist" error while creating a trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have spent a lot of time investigating this error and couldn't find a solution.

I am trying to create a trigger function and a trigger and then call the procedure when the `when ()` condition in the trigger evaluates to true. But I'm getting an error while creating the trigger:

> ```
> ERROR:  column new.total does not exist
> LINE 3:  FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.total * 80 / 100 >= 80) EXECUTE PROCEDURE...
> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "new.total".
> ```

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.totalInventory_events()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
     PERFORM pg_notify('notification', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
     RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_on_totalinventory
 AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON users
 FOR EACH ROW 
 WHEN (new.total * 80 / 100 >= 80)
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE totalInventory_events();
```

Why the error, and how to fix it?

Comment: Start with your actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script) and Postgres version.

Answer (score 3):

The *Hint* in the error message suggests that you have a column of the name `"new.total"` - containing the [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) "new", and a dot (!). The otherwise illegal identifier forced with double-quotes. A very unfortunate, misleading choice.

Your trigger definition would have to read:

```
...
WHEN (NEW."new.total" * 80 / 100 >= 80)
...
```

My standing advice is to use legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers to avoid any such confusion. I would also call the function `total_inventory_events()`, accordingly.

See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)

Comment: Hi Erwin, Thank you for your response. I had to enclose my column name within double quotes and it finally it worked. I only had to do NEW."total"

Comment: @Digant: That doesn't seem to make sense. `total` is not a reserved word and does not require double quotes. If you provided your exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement), like you should in any case, this would be easy.